# How to get IIS6 to respond to the OPTIONS verb?

Tags: iis-6, options, httpverbs

I have a WCF webservice hosted in IIS6 that another site will POST to in a cross domain manner using jquery.

Because it is a cross domain POST, the browser first sends an OPTIONS verb with Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
However, IIS6 does not respond back with anything.

Is this something that I need to handle at a web service level or something at the IIS level?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is it giving you in the response?  Also, how exactly is the OPTIONS request formed?  You should be good unless you've manually disabled OPTIONS using something like [**URLScan**](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1755).

Comment: I've the same problem and don't have URLScan installed. In my case it returns 403 for every OPTIONS request

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `.svc` mapping (if that is the URL you're using) in IIS6 in the website's *Properties -> Home Directory -> Configuration -> Mappings -> .svc -> Edit -> Limit Verbs* to explicitely allow the `OPTIONS` verb. That will allow you to receive `OPTIONS` requests in your WCF application and deal with them however you like (e.g. return `Access-Control-` headers in the `Global.asax`'s `Begin_Request` method).